# how can we update OneToOneField through serializer in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have 2 model country and user, User has relation with country

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'country'

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, related_name='country_model')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 12)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User'
```

I have write down serializer for User

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_detail = CountrySerializer(source = 'country',required=False)
    class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['country','name','country_detail']
```

Now in view i have write down this

```
obj = User.objects.get(pk = 996)
#data pass this
{"name": "abc" , "country":"545"}
UserSerializer(obj, data) # it show me error type object 'User' has no attribute country 'DoesNotExit'
```

if i remove OneToOneField relation there then i will save data without an error

what wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

Once you specify another name (country_detail) for the country field in the UserSerializer, this is the field you should pass to the UserSerializer during creation of users, like so:

```
obj = User.objects.get(pk = 996)
#data passed: 
{"name": "abc" , "country_detail":"545"}
UserSerializer(obj, data)
```